# Using grep and gawk in Perl

Tags: perl, formatting, awk, grep, cgi

```
    $chosenbeer = param('beers');
    $beerprice = `grep "$chosenbeer" beers | gawk '{gsub(/[a-zA-Z\t ]/,"");print $1}'`;
```

This is the code I'm trying to use, $chosenbeer is the string of a list from a CGI page previously. I'm trying to get the price of the beer selected.

beers ex line:

```
Dogfish Head 60 Minute IPA      35.96
```

But for some reason this isn't working. Any idea why? When I print $beerprice nothing comes out.

Comment: `perl` subsumes both `grep` and `awk`; why are you running either one?  Do it in your `perl` script.

Comment: geekosaur is right, but why would you use `gsub`? Why not `print $NF` to get the last field on the line?

Comment: Your code contains a very large security hole.  Consider a beer called `" .; echo "Owned";`

Comment: When I run your `grep | gawk` from the command line, I get "6035.96" as the price.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this better in Perl without shelling out.  Should be faster, more flexible, more portable, a lot easier to debug and doesn't contain a large security hole.

```
sub find_beer {
    my $beer = shift;

    open my $fh, "beers" or die $!;

    # Take the first beer that matches
    my($line) = grep /\Q$beer/, <$fh>;
    return unless $line;

    # I'm presuming the name and price are separated by a hard tab.
    my($name, $price) = split /\t/, $line;

    return { name => $name, price => $price };
}

my $beer = find_beer("Dogfish Head 60 Minute IPA");
print $beer->{price}, "\n";
```

Comment: Well there is this issue now, let me explain. I have this code selecting the beer:


`scrolling_list( -name=>'beers')

....

$tempbeer=param('beers');
my $chosenbeer = find_beer("$tempbeer");`

but nothing is showing up when I do
`print $chosenbeer->{price};`

Comment: @hutherca 1) Turn on strict and warnings.  2) Does anything show up when you print anything?  3) Does it work from the command line (see the DEBUGGING section of the CGI.pm docs).